# How to push array in to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Hi I am working on AngularJS and try to push array in to array:
This is what I tried:

```
$scope.addPositionInUpdateEditor = function (index) {
      $scope.updatePlayersPositionsArray[index].push('PF');
    }
```

I get error **Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**.
$scope.updatePlayersPositionsArray is this type of array:  `[0:Array(1)[0: "QB"],1: {}]`
I want to push 'PF' value to first array in array result should look like this:

```
[0:Array(2)[0: "QB", 1: "PF"],1: {}]
```

How should I do that?

Comment: What is the value of `index`? If it's anything other than 0 you get that error. (And if you want to push to the first element, why use a parameter at all?)

Comment: Thanks, the index was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `concat` method. As the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) says:

> The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method **does not change** the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.

There is also other options that you can use, those are the following:

- `push` — add elements to the end of the array. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- `unshift` — add elements to the beginning of the array. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift).